# C# Byte conversions

Tags: c#

I get very confused when it comes up to byte conversation.

I need to do two convertions:

1.We have a byte[] array { 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35 };

How do I convert it to string so I get "30 31 32 33 34 35".

2.We have the same byte[] array

Now I need to convert it to ASCII(0x30 = 0, 0x31 = 1, 0x32 = 2 and so on)

When done I should get "012345".

How do I make both conversions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var bytearr = new byte[] { 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35 };
var str = bytearr.Select(x => x.ToString("x2"));
var ascii = bytearr.Select(x => (char)x);
```

If you want the output as a single `string` (as opposed to `IEnumerable`s), you could do:

```
var str = String.Join(" ", bytearr.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
var ascii = new string(bytearr.Select(x => (char)x).ToArray());
```

Comment: You need a ToString() in that second ascii assignment I think

var ascii = String.Join("", bytearr.Select(x => ((char)x).ToString()).ToArray());

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for pointing it out. I blindly copy pasted them from above and forgot to do so ;) I switched to a better approach (`new string(char[])`)

Answer (score 0):

1. This will format the numbers as hexadecimal with spaces between:

   string r1 = String.Join(" ", array.Select(n => n.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
2. This will convert the bytes to ASCII:

   string r2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array);